# Ada: Create a type of a generic instantiation (e.g. Vectors)

Tags: types, rename, ada

I am trying to create a type 'Path' which is a vector of points:

```
with Ada.Containers.Vectors;
use Ada.Containers;
package Geometry is

    type Point is record
        North : Integer := 0; -- millimetres
        East  : Integer := 0;
    end record;
    function Same_Point (A, B : Point) return Boolean is
      (A.North = B.North and then A.East = B.East);

    package Path_Points is new Vectors
      (Element_Type => Point,
       Index_Type   => Positive,
       "="          => Same_Point);
    use Path_Points;
    -- works, but poor readability. 'result' is a 'path', not a vector
    Result : Vector; 
    
    -- What I'd like to do, a type called 'Path':
    type Path is new Path_Points.Vector; -- WRONG

end Geometry;
```

So that when I with & use Geometry, I can write

```
    Result : Path; -- Easy to understand!
```

How can I create a type 'Path' which is simply an alias for Ada.Containers.Vectors.Vector?

I realise that I could create, OOP-style, a 'Private Type Path' and implement all the plumbing to replicate the Vectors functions, but it seems terribly clumsy.

Comment: "a 'Private Type Path' and implement all the plumbing to replicate the Vectors functions". No, you would implement the full type and its operations in terms of a hidden instantiation of Vectors. This is the correct route if you want package Geometry to implement a Path abstraction.

Comment: Why do you define `Same_Point`? `"="` is defined for `Point` and does the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `Vector` type is a `tagged` type, which means you need a type extension instead of just a derivation:

```ada
type Path is new Path_Points.Vector with null record;
```

I'm guessing the compiler hinted at this in the error message?

EDIT: Before the comments below drags out to a longer discussion, let me clear up some confusion:

Types don't have names in Ada, only subtypes do, so a type declaration (including type derivations, which creates new types)
is really a declaration of an anonymous type, alongside its `first subtype`.

Derived types inherit the primitive operations of the base type, as if they were declared with the new type.
They are only compatible with the base type through explicit type conversions, so you cannot call the operations
of the base type with a derived type as a parameter without a conversion. There is rarely a need for that,
though, because the operations are inherited.

Subtypes, on the other hand, work as a renaming  of the base type (they can also have constraints, but that is outside this discussion),
and does not inherit the primitive operations, but must rely on the base type for their operations. They are, on the other hand,
compatible (without type conversion) with the base type.

thus

```ada
type Foo is null record;
procedure Process(Item : in out Foo);
```

is conceptually:

```ada
type @anonymous_type is null record;
procedure Process(Item : in out @anonymous_type);

subtype Foo is @anonymous_type;
```

and

```ada
type Bar is new Foo;
```

is conceptually:

```ada
type @derived_type is new @anonymous_type;
procedure Process(Item : in out @derived_type); -- implicit declaration of inherited subprogram

subtype Bar is @derived_type;
```

whereas a

```ada
subtype Baz is Foo;
```

is just that. A new name.

The practical implications of all this comes into play when types are derived or subtyped outside
their own scope,

```ada
with Ada.Strings.Unbounded;
package Foo is
   subtype Bar is Ada.Strings.Unbounded.Unbounded_String;
   -- Bar is a subtype; no inheritance, must call operations on the base type
   Foobar : constant Bar := Ada.Strings.Unbounded.To_Unbounded_String("Foobar");
  
   type Baz is new Ada.Strings.Unbounded.Unbounded_String;
   -- Baz is a derived type, inherited operations are directly visible in its scope
   Foobaz : constant Baz := To_Unbounded_String("Foobaz");


   -- However:
  
   -- This is not legal for a subtype (without a `use` clause):
   -- Foobar : constant Bar := To_Unbounded_String("Foobar");


   -- This is not legal for a derived type (without an explicit type conversion):
   --  Foobaz : constant Bar := Ada.Strings.Unbounded.To_Unbounded_String("Foobaz");
end Foo;
```

As now becomes clear, derived types can significantly reduce the typing needed internally in your package (even without a `use` clause).

Similarly, derived types can reduce the typing needed, and the number of dependencies (and potentially `use` clauses) needed for any users of your API:

Notice how a subtype forces the user to `with` the scope of the base type

```ada
with Foo;
with Ada.Strings.Unbounded;
procedure Bar_Test is
   Bar : Foo.Bar := Ada.Strings.Unbounded.To_Unbounded_String("Foobar");

   -- illegal for a subtype
   -- Bar : Foo.Bar := Foo.To_Unbounded_String("Foobar");
begin
   null;
end Bar_Test;
```

Where a derived type does not

```ada
with Foo; -- Baz is a derived type, inherited operations are visible in Foo
procedure Baz_Test is
   Baz : Foo.Baz := Foo.To_Unbounded_String("Foobaz");

   -- illegal for a derived type, type conversion needed
   -- Baz : Foo.Baz := Ada.Strings.Unbounded.To_Unbounded_String("Foobaz");
begin
   null;
end Baz_Test;
```

A type extension is defined as a special case of derived type where the base type is a tagged record type,
enabling us to extend a record with more members:

```ada
type Foo is tagged
record
   M1 : Natural;
end record;

procedure Process(Item : in out Foo);


type Bar is new Foo with
record
   M2 : Natural; -- Bar has both members M1 and M2
end record;

-- implicit declaration of Process for Bar, unless Process is overridden (as for Baz below)


type Baz is new Foo with null record; -- no new members, Baz has only M1

overriding
procedure Process(Item : in out Baz); -- Process is overridden
```

The `overriding` keyword is optional, but recommeded.
There's also a similar `not overriding` to avoid accidental overriding

Tagged types and type extensions also enables dynamic dispatching on a class of types

```ada
Dispatch : Foo'Class := Baz'(Foo with M1 => 1337);
```

`Foo'Class` is called a classwide type, and can hold a `Foo` or any type rooted in `Foo` (derived/extended from `Foo`)

They also enable more advanced features like multiple inheritance in the form of `interface`,
prefixed views of subprograms (better known as the Object.Dot notation), Controlled types, etc.

Comment: Probably better `subtype Path is Path_Points.Vector`?

Comment: Yes, I realised it was hinting, but I couldn't figure out the answer ("you need a type extension instead of just a derivation" isn't at all obvious). Thanks for the quick answers Gentlemen, both very instructive, I'm most grateful. Ada is hard for beginners eh? >;-)

Comment: One can use the declaration of a subtype as a means to "rename" another subtype.

Comment: @JimRogers, @SimonWrighht Yes, but there are subtle differences. A derived type creates a new distinct type, so there's no confusion between apples and oranges, a subtype does not . And a derived type inherits the primitive operations of the parent, whereas a subtype does not. This will have impact when exposing such a type in the API of a package, In most cases, I would want to do `Foo := Geometry.To_Vector(...);` rather than `Foo := Geometry.Path_Points.To_Vector(...);`

Comment: @smirkingman, I was trying to hint that you should have put the actual error message in your question, rather than just `-- WRONG` ;-)

Comment: @egilhh, section 3.4 of the ARM states "
A derived_type_definition defines a derived type (and its first subtype) whose characteristics are derived from those of a parent type, and possibly from progenitor types." Note that the definition of named type or derived type also defines the name of its first subtype. Subtypes do not have the limitations you claim.

Comment: @JimRogers, Try it, then. That quote says nothing about the behaviour of subtypes, btw

Comment: @egilhh, Yes it does. "A derived_type_definition defines a derived type (and its first subtype) ..." If subtypes did not inherit primitive operations of its base type then it would be impossible to use base types, since the published name of the base type is its first derived type.

Comment: @JimRogers, a mention of `first subtype` does not describe the behaviour of subtypes. Instead, take a look a RM 3.2 and 3.2.2. Anyway, I have updated my answer to clear up any confusion. Hope it helps